# Why LiveData observer is not called? (Android, Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, observers

My Observer is not called even though the LiveData value changes. What am I doing wrong?

The observer and the model are initialized in a fragment. A button is used to change the value in the model via a method (calculation followed by a set method). However, the observer does not register any change of the model value.

**Fragment**

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    private PlayerViewModel mViewModel;
    private ImageButton volumeUp, volumeDown;

    public static PlayerFragment newInstance() {
        return new PlayerFragment();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       
        volumeDown = getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_player_volume_down);
        volumeDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewModel.volumeDown();
            }
        });

        volumeUp = getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_player_volume_up);
        volumeUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewModel.volumeUp();
            }
        });

        final Observer<Integer> volumeObserver = new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer volValue) {
                SeekBar volume = getView().findViewById(R.id.player_volumeBar);
                volume.setProgress( volValue );
            }
        };

        mViewModel.getVolume().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), volumeObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PlayerViewModel.class);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle( getString(R.string.fragment_player_title) );
        mViewModel.fetchPlayerData();
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class PlayerViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> volume;

    public PlayerViewModel(){
        volume = new MutableLiveData<Integer>();
        fetchPlayerData();
    }

    public void fetchPlayerData(){
        volume = new MutableLiveData<Integer>(1);
    }
    public void volumeUp() {
        volume.postValue( volume.getValue() + 5 );
        Log.i( "volumeUp", "Set new volume:" + volume.getValue().toString() );
    }

    public void volumeDown() {
        volume.postValue( volume.getValue() - 5 );
        Log.i( "volumeDown", "Set new volume:" + volume.getValue().toString() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `fetchPlayerData()` assigns `volume` a new MutableLiveData, which causes the observer that was registered on the old one to be lost. It's called in `onResume()` again, after the observer was registered.

You could change `fetchPlayerData()` to something like this:

```
volume.postValue(1)
```